# How to transform xml into json (and vice versa) if the data contains lists?

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson

I'm trying to create a simple xml-json conversor with Jackson (version 2.9.4), but I have a problem with lists.

```
package testes;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String x = "{\"a\":[{\"b\":1,\"c\":true,\"d\":\"teste\"},{\"b\":2,\"c\":false,\"d\":\"texto\"}]}";
        System.err.println("original: " + x);
        x = jsonToXml(x);
        System.err.println("xml: " + x);
        x = xmlToJson(x);
        System.err.println("json: " + x);
    }

    private static final ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper().setDefaultUseWrapper(true);

    public static final String jsonToXml(String json) throws Exception {
        final JsonNode node = jsonMapper.readTree(json);
        return xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(node);
    }

    public static final String xmlToJson(String xml) throws Exception {
        final JsonNode node = xmlMapper.readTree(xml);
        return jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(node);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
original: {"a":[{"b":1,"c":true,"d":"teste"},{"b":2,"c":false,"d":"texto"}]}
xml: <ObjectNode><a><b>1</b><c>true</c><d>teste</d></a><a><b>2</b><c>false</c><d>texto</d></a></ObjectNode>
json: {"a":{"b":"2","c":"false","d":"texto"}}
```

Is it possible to adjust the settings so that lists are correctly converted between formats?

I undestand that the property

> .setDefaultUseWrapper(true);

should have done the job.

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library has static methods U.jsonToml(json) and U.xmlToJson(xml).

JSON:

```
{"a":[{"b":1,"c":true,"d":"teste"},{"b":2,"c":false,"d":"texto"}]}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <a>
    <b number="true">1</b>
    <c boolean="true">true</c>
    <d>teste</d>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b number="true">2</b>
    <c boolean="true">false</c>
    <d>texto</d>
  </a>
</root>
```